# Enforce Terraform to apply new state file every time - S3 File Upload scenario

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Please pardon me if the question is against the protocol generally enforced by Terraform.

I have come up with a utility to upload file in a S3 bucket using Terraform. It works fine in uploading the file.

The problem comes when I try to upload a new file again where the previous one gets removed. Terraform plan makes a comparison of what is there existing and what is being applied and removes the previously uploaded file.

Is there a way I can overcome this problem using state management in Terraform ?

It is a simple resource that I have created to upload the file/object onto the bucket

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_automation_upload1" {
          bucket = ""
          key = ""
          source = ""
          kms_key_id = ""
  }
```

**Step 1**

```
  resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_automation_upload1" {
          bucket = "bucket1"
          key = "folder1/"
          source = "File1.txt"
          kms_key_id = ""
  }
```

File1.txt is uploaded in bucket1 under "folder1"

**Step 2 - Again Terraform apply**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_automation_upload1" {
          bucket = "bucket1"
          key = "folder1/"
          source = "File2.txt"
          kms_key_id = ""
  }
```

Now File2.txt is uploaded but File1.txt is removed by Terraform as there is a new state change.

What should be done to retain File1.txt and just File2.txt should be only added

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what do you want to achieve. You overwrite the file uploaded by TF, and TF then replaces the file with the old version?

Comment: Yes Terraform Seem to replace the file. Let me update in the detail the scenario in the question itself

Comment: A utility to upload files using Terraform is not a good idea. That's not what Terraform is designed for, and you are seeing problems as a result. The AWS CLI tool, and all the AWS SDKs already exist. Why do you need to do this with Terraform?

Comment: @MarkB we do not have direct  control to add using AWS GUI. Hence taking the Terraform route. We do not have exclusive permission as a user with roles to upload/download/delete objects in S3 in the organization

Comment: None of the much better things that I listed in my comment utilize the AWS GUI. Terraform is an awesome tool, but it is for provisioning cloud resources, and a small part of that is being able to copy some files to S3 when it is provisioning your resources. It is not the right tool for building an S3 file copy utility like you are doing. The AWS CLI, or one of the AWS SDKs are much more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comments that Terraform is likely not the ideal tool for this job (something like `aws s3 sync ...` would be a better place to start), but taking your question at face value ...

I think your problem is the `key` specification. This should be the key for the object being stored. Your current solution is managing the folder, not the files contained within, and therefore the contents are getting replaced each time you change the source. Try this instead:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_automation_upload1" {
          bucket = "bucket1"
          key = "folder1/File1.txt"
          source = "File1.txt"
          kms_key_id = ""
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_automation_upload2" {
          bucket = "bucket1"
          key = "folder1/File2.txt"
          source = "File2.txt"
          kms_key_id = ""
}
```

Bear in mind that Terraform is designed to manage individual, discrete resources and so using this method, each file uploaded to S3 will require its own Terraform resource.